# Determine which grid page will have a specific record to display it on the screen

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using a grid with paging, which is fetching data using Linq:

```cs
Context.Table.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(filter)).OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Now I need a grid to automatically show the specific record in the UI. So I need to find a page and a relative position on that page for this record.

To find a row number I can use SQL like this:

```sql
select rn
from (
  select row_number() over (order by id) rn, id
  from table a
  where a.name like 'test%'
  --and global filters here
) a
where id = @recordId
```

And then calculate `page = rn / pageSize` and `position = rn % pageSize`

**How can I make this SQL query using Linq and EF Core?** (So other settings like dynamic ordering and global filters can take place automatically.)

I need somenting like this:

```cs
Context.Table
    .Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(filter))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Id)
    .Select((a, index) => new { Row = a, Index = index })
    .Where(a => a.Row.Id == recordId)
    .Select(a => a.Index)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But this code throws an exception:

> This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is
>   currently not supported.

Comment: Try following : var results = a.Where(x => x.id == @recordId).Select((x,i) => new { page = x.page, position = x.rn % @pageSize, index = i}).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng my table in EF Core doesn't contain field 'page' and 'rn', they are calculated fields, that I don't know how to make using Linq.

Comment: You need to declare these values as variables in c# and use the same formulas that are used in the sql server.

Comment: @jdweng I need to calculate row number in sql for one specific record. What variables can I do in c# for that?

Comment: You can't.  Data in SQL Server is not stored in any particular order.  SQL Server is multi-threaded and the order that you retrieve data is random.  You must do an OrderBy to make sure you always get data in the same order.

Comment: @jdweng I always add OrderBy to my paged queries. I don't know how to get row number in EF Core, not how to do SQL

Comment: Once you do the order by then it is .Select((x,i) =>  where i is the row number starting at zero.  See my posting above.

Comment: @jdweng When I call Select with index on my DbSet, I get an error: "This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported." And I don't need a list, I need to get one row number for one specific row from the SQL, to know what page to fetch next.

Comment: What does your query look like.  Edit posting with your c# query.

Comment: I need something like Context.Table.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(filter)).OrderBy(a => a.Id).Select((a, index) => new { Row = a, Index = index }).Where(a => a.Row.Id == recordId).Select(a => a.Index).FirstOrDefault(), but this is not supported

Comment: The code should work if you have a List object.  I'm not sure what part isn't supported. Is Context.Table an enumerable object?  If it is a DataTable usually you have to use Context.Table.AsEnumerable() to get the rows of the table.  If it is already a List object then I do not know where the issue is.  I do not know why you are using FirstOrDefault() I would assume you are getting more than one item and should be ToList().

Comment: @jdweng Context.Table is an EF Core DbSet with million of records. I can't afford client side evaluation. I use FirstOrDefault because my question is about how to get one cocrete row number of one specific record in a table. So I can open required page of the grid to show this record to the user.

Comment: @djweng No, I can not make a linq query which will return me a row number for the specific record. I don't need to get a record or a list, I need to get a number, one number calculated in the Sql